# Automatically `git add` after conflicts are resolved in vim

Tags: git

Coming from Spacemacs, one of the things that I miss is that files are automatically `git add`ed after all conflicts are resolved. Wondering if there's a way to do that in vim.

Answer (score 2):

When invoked with `git mergetool`, where the `mergetool.<tool>.trustExitCode` variable is `true`, then exiting Vim will mark the conflict as resolved in Git. Conversely, exiting via `:cquit` with no arguments (or a non-zero argument) will *not* cause Git to consider the conflict resolved.

---

With fugitive, I have `merge.tool = fugitive` and `merge.fugitive.cmd = vim --nofork +\"Git mergetool\"`, along with the `trustExitCode = true` as mentioned. Git's support for Vim (*sans* fugitive) has improved dramatically lately, so you should check the default configurations and adjust them as specified/desired.

Comment: Hmm, I want to not have to worry about the exit code though, I want some autodetection of whether or not it's been resolved...

Comment: @CarlDong and my approach is: it's been resolved if I save-and-quit from Vim normally. If I don't, it hasn't. Git isn't smart enough to inspect the content and tell you the conflict is resolved because it doesn't (and couldn't) understand the content. Perhaps you could describe more (or point to docs) about how Spacemacs knows when the conflicts are resolved?

Comment: Didn't take a look at the Spacemacs code but I just found out that `git diff --check` will indicate if there are leftover conflict markers. Might use that to script the automation. Thanks!

Comment: I've had Git incorrectly flag a text file with `=====` as having conflict markers, so beware false-positives @CarlDong